# What does the Finished status mean in Chrome Network View

Tags: ajax, rest, google-chrome, http

We have an application that uses ExtJs for the frontend and makes many ajax calls, most of which are RESTful JSON. In a rare few cases, we see one of our normal common requests not returning data. In the Chrome dev console, in the Network view, the requests show up in a status of Finished with size of 0 Bytes. It does not look the same as what we see for local cache hits (i.e. 200 'from cache'). No network calls are actually being made according to wireshark. I could not find much on the web describing this state.

What does the Finished state mean and what is typically the cause?